# Conversion between number systems hexToBin and binToHHex fails (C#)

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I have programmed a calculator in C#. The calculating part i working fine, and I want to add a function for switching between decimal, binary and hexadecimal.
In order to convert the number in the display (textBox) I have made a couple of methods. 4 of 6 works. hexToBin and binToHex are not working. The textBox still displays the number in the first base. BUT, note, the program does not fail. When I enter a number in bin, (try to) convert it to hex and then choose dec, it displays the number in decimal correctly.

EDIT: In this switch I try to find where the problem is. I figured out that the MessageBoxes never are shown. Is the case 'H' never true?

```
        switch (talbas)
        {
            case 'D':
                {
                    //Dec till Bin
                    output = decTillBin(textBoxDisplay.Text);
                }
                break;
            case 'H':
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Hex till Bin");
                    //Hex till Bin
                    output = hexTillBin(textBoxDisplay.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show(output);
                }
                break;
        }
```

Here is the code for the radioButtons. (Comments and names are in Swedish, but I think you will understand)¨

```
 private void radioButtonDec_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(radioButtonHex.Checked)
            {
                button0.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = true;
                button4.Enabled = true;
                button5.Enabled = true;
                button6.Enabled = true;
                button7.Enabled = true;
                button8.Enabled = true;
                button9.Enabled = true;
                buttonA.Enabled = true;
                buttonB.Enabled = true;
                buttonC.Enabled = true;
                buttonD.Enabled = true;
                buttonE.Enabled = true;
                buttonF.Enabled = true;
                buttonDeci.Enabled = false;
                buttonTeckenByte.Enabled = false;
                switch (talbas)
                {
                    case 'D': 
                        {
                            //Dec till Hex
                            output = decTillHex(textBoxDisplay.Text);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'B': 
                        {
                            //Bin till Hex
                            output = binTillHex(textBoxDisplay.Text);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                textBoxDisplay.Text = output;
                talbas = 'H';
            }
        else if (radioButtonBin.Checked)
        {
            button0.Enabled = true;
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            button5.Enabled = false;
            button6.Enabled = false;
            button7.Enabled = false;
            button8.Enabled = false;
            button9.Enabled = false;
            buttonA.Enabled = false;
            buttonB.Enabled = false;
            buttonC.Enabled = false;
            buttonD.Enabled = false;
            buttonE.Enabled = false;
            buttonF.Enabled = false;
            buttonDeci.Enabled = false;
            buttonTeckenByte.Enabled = false;

            switch (talbas)
            {
                case 'D':
                    {
                        //Dec till Bin
                        output = decTillBin(textBoxDisplay.Text);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hex till Bin");
                        //Hex till Bin
                        output = hexTillBin(textBoxDisplay.Text);
                        MessageBox.Show(output);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            textBoxDisplay.Text = output;
            talbas = 'B';
        }
        else if(radioButtonDec.Checked)
        {
            if (talbas == 'B')
            {
                //Bin till Dec
                output = binTillDec(textBoxDisplay.Text);
            }
            else if (talbas == 'H')
            {
                //Hex till Dec
                output = hexTillDec(textBoxDisplay.Text);
            }

                textBoxDisplay.Text = output;
                button0.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = true;
                button4.Enabled = true;
                button5.Enabled = true;
                button6.Enabled = true;
                button7.Enabled = true;
                button8.Enabled = true;
                button9.Enabled = true;
                buttonA.Enabled = false;
                buttonB.Enabled = false;
                buttonC.Enabled = false;
                buttonD.Enabled = false;
                buttonE.Enabled = false;
                buttonF.Enabled = false;
                buttonDeci.Enabled = true;
                talbas = 'D';
        }
        textBoxDisplay.Text = output;

    }
```

And the methods looks like this:

```
    //Byt talsystem
    private string binTillDec(string input)
    {
        //Bin till dec
        decInt = Convert.ToInt32(input, 2);
        decString = decInt.ToString();
        string returnValue = decString;

        return(returnValue);
    }

    private string hexTillDec(string input)
    {
        //Hex till Dec
        decInt = Convert.ToInt32(input, 16);
        decString = decInt.ToString();
        string returnValue = decString;

        return (returnValue);
    }

    private string decTillBin(string input)
    {
        //Dec till Bin
        decInt = int.Parse(input);
        binString = Convert.ToString(decInt, 2);
        string returnValue = binString;

        return (returnValue);
    }

    private string decTillHex(string input)
    {
        //Dec till Hex
        decInt = int.Parse(input);
        hexString = decInt.ToString("X");
        string returnValue = hexString; ;

        return (returnValue);
    }

    private string binTillHex(string input)
    {
        //Bin till Hex

        //Bin till dec
        decInt = Convert.ToInt32(input, 2);
        //Dec till Hex
        hexString = decInt.ToString("X");
        string returnValue = hexString;

        return (returnValue);
    }

    private string hexTillBin(string input)
    {
        //Hex till Bin

        //Hex till Dec
        decInt = Convert.ToInt32(input, 16);
        //Dec till Bin
        binString = Convert.ToString(decInt, 2);
        string returnValue = binString;

        return (returnValue);
    }
```

Comment: Your UI code isn't really relevant here, assuming it's actually the conversion which is the problem, rather than the UI (and you should do appropriate research first using a debugger to check which of those cases is correct). What would be far more useful would be a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including hard-coded sample input, and then expected output vs real output... you haven't actually described what goes wrong at the moment.

Comment: What is the value of `talbas`? Can you debug it to inspect what it really is (instead of what you expect it to be)?

Comment: When I step through the debuger I realize that nothing is happening at all when the radioButtons change state from bin to hex and vice versa.It seems like it don not even come to the switch.

Comment: I got it! I just check if the decButtons state is changed. When going fro bin to hex or hex to bin dec is not influensed at all, that is why nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Library class to convert numbers between any number bases (from 2 to 36), See [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16872/Number-base-conversion-class-in-C).

I hope that helps you.

Comment: This is a link-only answer - these are discouraged on Stack Overflow, as links can become invalid over time, and without visiting the target page, the answer effectively has no information.